# Reading serial port windows 7 timeout/packets loss

Tags: windows, serial-port, timeout

I have a fiscal printer(*) Epson TM-U950 with a serial (com) port. I have it connected via [Prolific PL2303 HXA](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?pcid=37&showlevel=0017-0037) com->usb switcher: FPrinter->ComToUsb->Win7.

I need to program a device wrapper.

It sends packets fine, but losts some packets on read (i think it reads only small packets, not higher 8 bytes). So i tried to send/receive commands via native driver. Sends ok, but on receive it timeouts, same problem!

Finally i try this scheme on WinXP, and what do you think? It works fine!
The settings on both machines are the same.

I dont know what to think. So i need your assumptions and council.

(*) A [fiscal printer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiscal_memory_devices) (FP) is a specific type of cash register that can operate only together with a personal computer.

Comment: I have edited your question (it was a wall of text). Now you add your code to it. Without code we can't help you.

Comment: Finally, after 3 days of manipulating, i turned off driver sign check, and manually installed WinXP drivers on Win7 and it works fine! So keep in mind, prolific PL2303 Win7 drivers does not works right! So it was a driver problem! Can not understand, why no one is faced with the problem before...

Comment: Maybe not that many people use your setup + write your code ;-) BTW You can write a (detailed) answer to your own question, then after some delay (2 days?) marks it as the correct answer.

Comment: Did you notify Prolific?

Comment: And I have edited your post again mentioning the model number.

Comment: The model number is Prolific PL2303 HXA, yes i did notify Prolific.

Comment: Jan Doggen, thanks for help. Hope this solution will help to other people. By the way Fiscal Printer is Epson TM-U950, maybe it plays a role in the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Prolific PL2303 Win7 drivers does not works right! So the solution is to install Windows XP drivers manually, and it works great! So keep in mind, if you can not read data from buffer via PL2303 ComToUsb, try to install WinXP drivers.

Comment: Can you accept this answer so that it doesn't show up on the unanswered questions list?  Thanks.